# Можно ли перехватывать управление консолью из программы?

Tags: linux, c, bash, консоль

Работаю в Ubuntu. В программе на Си при помощи `system("sudo su")` я вызываю терминал от админа. Необходимо ввести пароль, но `system("password")` срабатывает только после того, как я ввожу пароль непосредственно в терминале. Аналогичная ситуация при создании пользователя при помощи утилиты `htpasswd`. Там требуется дважды ввести пароль для пользователя. Как мне обойти это и полностью управлять терминалом из программы?

`Sleep` не помог, т.к он также срабатывает после.

Comment: Это вы не на Си пишите, а на shell.

Answer (score 2):

У программы `sudo` есть ключ `-S`. Этот ключ предписывает читать пароль из `stdin`, а не из консоли.

`system("echo PASSWORD | sudo -S su")` - вместо `PASSWORD` подставьте пароль вашего аккаунта.

**UPD**

Как же не работает? Вот простейшая программа `main.c`:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    return system("echo MYPASSWORD | sudo -S ls");
}
```

Вывод:

```
$ gcc main.c
$ ./a.out 
[sudo] password for user: a.out  main.c
```

Запрос пароля был напечатан, но сам пароль не потребовался, его `sudo` считал из `stdin`.

Comment: Это не работает. По прежнему запрашивает пароль. Может быть есть другие способы?

Comment: @lecosh что именно не работает? Ключ `-S` пароль для sudo вводить не требует. Что ещё вам нужно?

Comment: @lecosh если же вам нужно вводить пароль для каких-то ещё программ, то посмотрите `libexpect`. Эта библиотека позволяет ждать вывод программы, подсовывать ей произвольный ввод, мониторить stderr

Comment: Еще вариант про настройку судоерс для пользователя бы, без запроса пароля на определенную программу)